# Should I opt to use Blender for making animation in a month time? I am a beginner

Tags: rendering, animation

I am a beginner at using blender and just started using it. Is it possible for me to make a 2 minute animation in a month time or should I opt for 2D animation. For 2D animation should I use blender or any other software? Suggestions will be really helpful for me

Is it possible to make characters like these
[image]
[image]
Thanks everyone

Comment: Hi. Understand that is a Q&A site, and not a forum. People are here to provide clear, unambiguous answers to clear, unambiguous questions. Those who post questions should generally not seek opinions or general advice. Since you only have a month's time, it probably isn't a good idea to ask a question like yours here and then wait for a response. What you might consider instead is to begin an actual project now, even a simple one. As you proceed, questions will undoubtedly arise about how to solve particular problems. When you have some of those kinds of questions, feel free to ask them here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - it is certainly possible but also wholly dependent on the complexity and nature of the animation you want to achieve.

For example, you could produce a 2-minute animation moving simple primitive types (such as cubes and spheres and donuts) about on the screen within a day. Alternatively, it would take months or years to fully get to grips with creating and animating interacting, realistic humanoid figures.

For simple animation it can be as easy as moving objects in the viewport and moving through the timeline and hitting <kbd>I</kbd> to store a keyframe. More complicated is creating a complicated model, rigging it and animating manually or using motion capture.

Start small and build up over time. Ask specific questions here when you're stuck and you'll get some great answers from this community. I'm sure in a month you can make a lot of progress.